# How do I access data from an extended user profile in the template?

Tags: django, templates, view, model

I am trying to determine what I should include in the template below in order to pull in data inserted into the "quote" field of the model below.  Currently, nothing is showing up in the template.  Any advice?

## model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    quote = models.CharField('About', max_length =  200, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField('Personal website/blog', null=True, blank=True)
    #facebook = models.CharField('Facebook profile page', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('quote', 'website')
        widgets = {
            'quote': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 18, 'rows': 7, 'style': "width: 300px;"}),
        }
```

## view

```
@login_required 
def user_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if upform.is_valid():
            up = upform.save(commit=False)
            up.user = request.user
            up.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        upform = UserProfileForm()
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/edit_profile.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## template

```
{{user.quote}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{% for profile in user.userprofile_set.all %}
   {{profile.quote}}
{% endfor %}
```

`quote` is not field of `User` model, so first access `UserProfile` instance then access `quote`.